# Android x86 + VirtualBox

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox, android-x86

I try to install android x86 4.2 (I tried also 4.0 asus laptop and eeepc) to my VirtualBox. My pc configuration:

- Windows 7 x64
- Lenovo Y570, Intel Core i7
- NTFS file system

What I create in VirtualBox:

- Name: Android x86
- Type: Other (I tried Linux 2.4 x86 or Linux 2.6 x86 too)
- Version: Other/Unknow
- RAM: 512 Mb
- Create a virtual hard drive => VDI (or HDD) => Fixed size (or dynamically) => 3 Gb (or 6)

Than I start my device and see boot menu. If I try to run it without installation, I see

> Detecting Android-x86... found at /dev/sr0
>
> Warning: Not an ASUS product
>
> A N D R O I D

and nothing more happens. But now it must run like in different tutorials.

If I install, I try to format my Primary/Logical Bootable/Unbootable disk (FS type is Linux) from Choose Partition => Create/Modify partition.

I see very quickly disappearing line "could not find valid v7 on sda", than I see "can not mount /dev/sda1 Do you want to format it?" And I again go to Choose Partition menu.

Why emulator does not run?

Edited.
Answer: It's just a destiny. I installed VBox on my big pc with Win7 x32 and all is fine. On my Lenovo with the same config but with Win7 x64 it does not work. If u really wanna good android emulator, u can try [YouWave](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20youwave).

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Why emulator does not run?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about "not an asus product", it shows every time on boot, but then go on loading os. For the installation process, you should format your virtual hd, then after choosing it as partition to install os, installer should ask if you want to create a virtual sd too...does it ask it?

Comment: But if I try to format it, I see "could not find valid v7 on sda"

Answer (score 0):

I have HP430 Laptop with win 7. I had the same problem. But I figured out the solution.

While booting the computer with win7 I entered BIOS menu. There was a option to optimize pc for virtualization.I selected it. After that every thing ran smooth.

Later I noticed in virtual box that, in system settings the acceleration type was VT-x AMD, Nested Paging,PAE/NX. This was different before optimization.

Hope this gives some idea.